# Is it o.k. to bootstrap sample of a table from its proportions - and how to do so (in R)?

Tags: r, chi-squared-test, bootstrap, contingency-tables

I wish to create a confidence interval for a statistic calculated on a table (let's say the p.value of chisqr.test).

For this, I might sample a bootstrap sample with the same size, from a table with the proportions of the table I have.  And my questions are:

1. Is this a correct procedure to use, or is there some catch here that I might be missing?
2. How can a table be "sampled" in R?  (my first instinct is to "open up" the table using melt, then expend the table to rows, sample them, and fold the results back to a table.  Is there a better way?)

p.s: I am aware of the `simulate.p.value` switch in `chisqr.test` - my question is more general - does it make sense to use bootstrap in such a way.

Sample table if someone wishes to show something:

```r
(x <- matrix(c(12, 5, 7, 7), ncol = 2))
prop.table(x)

# undoing a table
as.data.frame(as.table(x)) # but how do we open up the rows now? -
```

**update**: this was answered in the comments thanks to chl.

Comment: An answer to the last comment in your code: `library(reshape); untable(data.frame(X1=gl(2,1),X2=gl(2,2)), c(12, 5, 7, 7))`.

Comment: Do you need to reproduce any of the marginals in the table?

Comment: Whuber - That was a question I didn't think about.  Let's say we wish to create a CI for the chi square statistic using bootstrapping, should we then preserve the marginals of the bootstrapped table to be the same as the ones we had?

Comment: @whuber - I was wondering why did you ask this question. I am curious, can you pls tell. The only reason I can think of is bootstrapping might not produce the same marginals. Am I thinking correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me see if I understand you correctly:

You have a contingency table say $M$ by $N$ and you calculate a statistic based on this table. You want a CI for this statistic and you don't have a theoretical CI (or may be you don't want to use it, due to some reason).

Generally, if you have a contingency table, the columns represent the possible levels of the response variable (here: $Y$ will have $N$ levels) and the rows represent the levels of the explanatory variables (here: $X$ will have $M$ levels).

Now if you want to bootstrap, you need to make sure that you couple $Y$s and $X$s together. That is, shuffle $(X_i, Y_i)$ together for $i$ from $1$ to total number of observations (note this will be greater than $MN$ unless all the entries in the table are $1$).

Basically, what you can do is translate your table to a "hypothetical" data set set by using row numbers as levels for your $X$s and the column number as the value for the corresponding $Y$s.

To make it mathematically clear:

Lets say your $(i, j)^{th}$ entry in the table is $a$, then you need to create, $a$ data points for which the value of $Y$ is $j$ (remember column number for $Y$ value) and $X$ value is $i$. Do the same for $i = 1 \ldots m$ and $j = 1 \ldots n$. Now you have a "hypothetical" data set. Bootstrap from this data set as you would do in linear regression, say $B$ number of times. Each of the newly generated data set is a bootstrap sample. For each of the bootstrapped sample calculate the corresponding contingency table (say for $Y=1$ how many $X$s=1, how may $X$s=2, ... , this will give you the (1,1), (2,1),... entry for your table). Calculate the statistic for each of the $B$ tables and you have the desired bootstrap distribution.

I don't know if this is what you meant by bootstrapping the table. Please let me know if you thought otherwise.

HTH

S.

Comment: Hi Suncoolsu - you got it right, that's what I was wondering on how to do.  And my question was - is it a reasonable solution for that question.  From your answer, I deduce that you believe it is valid to do it this way (Also chl directed me on where to look for implementing this within R, which is great).  Thanks for you input.  Tal

Answer (score 1):

I once asked similar [question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281561/random-sample-from-given-bivariate-discrete-distribution). Basically you sample from table the same way you sample vector.

Comment: thanks mpiktas. chl suggestion is also a good direction on how to handle such data.

Answer (score 0):

how to bootstrap a table ought to depend on how it was obtained. there are a few ways this can be done.

for example, one can sample n individuals and classify all of them into an $r\times c$ table. in this scenario, neither row nor column totals are fixed. it would then seem plausible that a bootstrap sample would take a sample of size n  with replacement from the original n respondents and classify them into an $r\times c$ table.

in another scenario, the row totals for the table could have been fixed in advance. in that case, one would draw with replacement a sample of  $n_{i+}$ individuals from the $n_{i+}$ individuals in row $i$, separately for each row.

does this make sense? [apologies if this restates what has already been said. i don't quite grasp all of it.]

i would like to reiterate @whuber's query on why you are asking this question. one usually does not speak of obtaining a CI for a statistic [such as a p-value]. can you clarify this a bit?

Comment: Hi Ronaf.  This came up when I learned about Cramer's V statistic for contingency tables.  I was wondering what the CI for it are, and found a way to get them - but hoped to validate my results using bootstrapping.  Cheers, Tal