# Checking expected counts when analyzing binary outcome and binary explanatory variable using GLM

Tags: generalized-linear-model, categorical-data, chi-squared-test, binary-data, fishers-exact-test

Understand that chi-squared test comparing two categorical variables is only valid when expected counts for each cell is at least 5. I have not read or heard that this needs to be checked when running a GLM for binary outcome with only one binary explanatory variable. Model has no other covariates. Do I still need to check this assumption when I am running a GLM such as binomial regression or log-binomial regression? Would the contrast p-value comparing the categories in the binary explanatory variable be valid if some of the expected cell counts is less than 5? How about the confidence intervals from the model? Should I consider exact confidence interval instead of the one derived from the model?

Comment: How many observations do you have? You have a 2x2 contingency table, if using a chisquare test you can simulate a p-value, if using logistic regression you can do something similar, like bootstrap or using a profile likelihood-based confidence interval. For bootstrap see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5691/is-it-o-k-to-bootstrap-sample-of-a-table-from-its-proportions-and-how-to-do-s

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen 151+52 patients in total. With 12 outcomes (events) in the 150 group and 3 outcomes (events) in the 52 group.